# group by date in laravel mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I'm using mongo and laravel. 
I'm getting data in periods of time, usually 30 days. I want to group the data by day. I've tried `$project` `$dayOfMonth` and group by  `day` but it grouping them in order of days in month and I want to be ordered in days in the period.
is there a way?

```
[
     '$match' => [
           "created_at" => [
               '$gte' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($thisMonth),
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
                    [
      '$project' => [
              'day' => [
              '$dayOfMonth' => [
              'date' => '$created_at',
               ]
         ],
      ]

 ],
 [
      '$group' => [
                 '_id' => '$day',
                  'count' => ['$sum' => 1],
          ],

 ],
```

sample:

```
  {#940
  flag::STD_PROP_LIST: false
  flag::ARRAY_AS_PROPS: true
  iteratorClass: "ArrayIterator"
  storage: array:16 [
    "_id" => ObjectId {#933
      +"oid": "5b2ff00e35826377be16ff82"
    }
    "orderNumber" => "10000"
    "userName" => "dGFraHRlLTkwMDQ2NDcyOJRbugaZlHWdMR+nCNzaUfY=" 
    "updated_at" => UTCDateTime {#938
      +"milliseconds": "1529868539000"
    }
    "created_at" => UTCDateTime {#939
      +"milliseconds": "1529868302000"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you please post some sample collection

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to converts a date object to a string according to a your desired format.

```
[ "$match" => [
  "created_at" => [ '$gte' => new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($thisMonth) ]
]],
[ "$group" => [
  "_id" => [ "$dateToString" => [ "format" => "%Y-%m-%d", "date" => "$created_at" ] ],
  "count" => [ "$sum" => 1 ]
]]
```